# " Type any has no subscript member in swift3.0 " how to resolve it?

Tags: ios, string, swift3

```
 do{
            //converting response to NsDictionary
            var myJSON:NSDictionary!
            myJSON=try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any] as NSDictionary!

                //getting the json response
            let questions:NSArray = myJSON["questions"] as! NSArray
            //looping through all the array
           for i in 0 ..< questions.count{
                //getting the json for each index
            //let i=0


            self.questionId = questions[i]["id"] as! Int
                let questionName:String = questions[i]["ques"] as! String?
                let questionopta:String = questions[i]["opta"] as! String!
                let questionoptb:String = questions[i]["optb"] as! String!
                let questionoptc:String = questions[i]["optc"] as! String!
                let questionoptd:String = questions[i]["optd"] as! String!
```

Comment: Tips: Try to not use NSArray/NSDictionary (especially when you are doing two casts: `as! [String:Any] as NSDictionary!`), use Swift Types. Also you need to specify which line is causing the issue. I guess that your issue is on the lines `let questionName`? If YES, ask you this: `questions` is a `NSArray`. But who told the compiler that `question[i]` is a dictionary and you can access its data with `["ques"]`?

Comment: thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
   do{
        var myJSON:[String:Any]!
        myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

        //getting the json response
        let questions = myJSON["questions"] as! [[String:Any]]
        //looping through all the array 
        for obj in questions{
            self.questionId = obj["id"] as! Int
            let questionName = obj["ques"] as! String
            let questionopta = obj["opta"] as! String
            let questionoptb = obj["optb"] as! String
            let questionoptc = obj["optc"] as! String
            let questionoptd = obj["optd"] as! String
```

> And please don't make force unwrap .. this code is just for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any] {

        for question in json["questions"] as? [[String : Any]] ?? [] {

            guard
                let questionId = question["quid"] as? Int,
                let questionName = question["ques"] as? String,
                let questionopta = question["opta"] as? String,
                let questionoptb = question["optb"] as? String,
                let questionoptc = question["optc"] as? String,
                let questionoptd = question["optd"] as? String else { continue }

            self.questionId = questionId

            // ...
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```